# Split large SQL backup

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3

I have a large SQL database (~1TB) that I'm trying to backup.

I can back it up fine but we want to store it offsite on Amazon S3, where the maximum object size is 5GB.

I thought I could split it by using multiple files, but it seems the maximum is 64 so I'm still ending up with 16GB chunks which are too big for S3.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Just check the documentation on backup and whether/how you can use multiple files. Simply googling for "sql server backup multiple files" will return a lot of answers (Yes you can, just add them in the dialog)

Comment: @AndrewDeighton non-programming question, no effort to find a solution, not even an attempt to google. This isn't a good question. Don't force *me* to downvote as well. BTW, databases get big. 1TB isn't considered all that big any more - 1PB is the latest single-machine SQL Server reference architecture. And file splitting/joining is definitely a very very *very* bad idea when talking about business-critical matters like backups.

Comment: @BenDurkin Azure offers cloud backup for SQL Server. You should probably consider *this* instead of splitting a full backup to 200 files.

Comment: @ PanagiotisKanavos : Thanks for offering a possible explanation - is the forum purely for programming only?  I'm not sure on that one - observation : it can't be very prominently specified if I've never noticed, or not enough for people like me to notice.  The tag says sql-server and amazon though - he does seem to say he's hit a limit of how many files he can split too though, so he must have at least tried it - does google answer that?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton it is, VERY prominently specified when you sign up, in Help and the Tour. It's also a VERY common reason to close a question and transfer it to another stackexchange site, like `dba` or `serverfault`. And a question where you have to check individual words to understand what happened is not a good question. Insulting or non-constructive comments also get deleted without warning.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I apologise for any perceived insult.  Actually I was trying to be constructive - I'm gonna knock something up that splits into 5GB chunks and rebuilds

Comment: @BenDurkin the size limit [is 5TB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-size-limit/) not 5GB. 5GB is the upload block size. That means that you can upload in chunks that are up to 5GB large. How did you try to upload the backups? Perhaps you should be looking for a different uploader, one that understands cloud storeage?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton check your first post again. And don't knock anything up. That's not how cloud storage works. There is no need to split or rebuild to upload 5TB, just use PUT blocks of up to 5GBs. A lot of programs like Cyberduck do that already

Answer (score 0):

The maximum blob size for S3 is 5TB, not 5GB. 5GB is only the largest object that can be uploaded with a single HTTP PUT.

All cloud providers follow the same pattern: instead of uploading one huge file and storing it as a single blob, they break it apart into blocks that they replicate across many disks. When you ask for data, the provider retrieves it from all these blocks. To the client though, the blob appears as a single object.

Uploading a large file requires blocks too. Instead of uploading a large file with a single upload operation (HTTP PUT) all providers require that you upload individual blocks and finally notify the provider that these blocks constitute one object. This way, you can re-upload only a single failed block in case of failure, the provider can commit each block while you send the next, they don't have to track and lock a large blob (on a large disk) waiting for you to finish uploading etc.

In your case, you'll have to use an uploader that understands cloud storage and uses multiple blocks, perhaps something like Cyberduck, or S3 specific command-line tools. Or write a utility that uses Amazon's SDK to upload the backup file in parts.

Amazon's documentation site offers examples for multipart uploads at [Uploading Objects Using Multipart Upload API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html). The [high-level examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html) demonstrate various ways to upload a large file. All calls though use multi-part uploads, eg the simplest call :

```
var client= new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
fileTransferUtility.Upload(filePath, existingBucketName);
```

will upload the file using multiple parts and use the file's path as its key. The most advanced example allows you to specify the part size, a different key, redundancy options etc:

```
var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = existingBucketName,
                FilePath = filePath,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy,
                PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.
                Key = keyName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
            };
fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param1", "Value1");
fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param2", "Value2");
fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
```